# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"page"' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: angular, object, observable, subscribe

I cannot retrieve the content of the object when I subscribe with observable. I would like to retrieve the number of `totalPages`.

This is my code:

```
  getProducts() {
    this.catServ.getProductByKeyWord(this.currentkeyword,this.currentPage, this.size)
      .subscribe(data=>{

        this.totalPages=data["page"].totalPages;

      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })  }
```

This is te structure of the object :

```
_embedded   {…}
_links  {…}
page:
    size    :2
    totalElements   :56
    totalPages  :28
    number  :0
```

The solution  `data.page.totalPages;` does not work.

Comment: Most probably, this.totalPages and data["page"].totalPages are of different types.

Comment: they are of the same type (number)

Comment: can you also post the error you get? because the way you did it should also work in theory

Comment: Number would be the types as you give. But Typescript would interpret the type as the type of first result it gets. If you are giving any, there is no need of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.totalPages=(data as any).page.totalPages
```

Thanks very much, your solution work and this also work

```
this.produits=data;
this.totalPages=this.produits.page.totalPages;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.subscribe(data=>{
```

I had the same issue, and simply giving the any type to data also works

```
.subscribe((data:any)=>{
 this.totalPages=data.page.totalPages;
```